# GitHub page is not showing background image, FF console shows couldn't load images

Tags: github-pages

I'm not understanding even though image files are present, why GH pages is not able to show them ?

This does work properly locally.

[GH Repo](https://github.com/vikramvi/Profile-card-component)

Code

```
background-image: url(/images/bg-pattern-top.svg),
url(/images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg);
```

Images folder

```
 ./images
```

FF Console Error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with below changes, but I'm not sure why was it working properly on local setup though ?

1. Change 1

   background-image: url("../images/bg-pattern-top.svg"),
   url("../images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg");
2. Change 2

   background-image: url("../images/bg-pattern-card.svg");
3. Change 3

   background-image: url("../images/bg-pattern-top.svg"),
   url("../images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg");

Is there VS Code plugin which will capture these kind of errors or shows good practices to be followed ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might missing some path.

1. Try console.log or etc your url() first is return your current link or not ?
2. After return same link with current page then add your image path. url(/images/profile.jpg)
3. Last check if images folder can be access on public. (* Dunno what to say but folder images can be access by type full url with image path. Like localhost/images/profile.jpg it will show image.)